self.bot.get_cog() self undefined in discord.py
I want to be able to select a catagory from a drop-down menu and display the docstrings for the commands in that catagory.
But it shows self is undefined
class OptionView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.select(placeholder = "Option", min_values=1, max_values=1, options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label=filename[:-3]) for filename in self.bot.get_cog()
        ])
    
    async def select_callback(self, interaction:discord.Interaction,select:discord.ui.Select):
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title='Commands',
                colour=discord.Color.blue()
            )

            self.disabled = True
            value = select.values[0] # command's catagory
            
            commands_list = [command.name for command in self.bot.get_cog(value).get_commands()]  # Get command names in the category

            for command in commands_list:
                cmd = self.bot.get_command(command)
                docstring = cmd.callback.__doc__ or "No docstring"
                embed.add_field(name=command, value=docstring, inline=True)
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
                
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,view=OptionView())

enter image description here

I meant self is undefined, it's only defined INSIDE the function, the decorator is OUTSIDE of it.

You can't access self outside the instance's methods. In your case, where you have variable options for your select, it is recommended that you define the options in the __init__ method using self.children[0] to access the select.
class OptionView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        super().__init__(timeout=300)
        options = [discord.SelectOption(label=filename[:-3]) for filename in bot.get_cog()]
        self.children[0].options = options

    @discord.ui.select(placeholder="Option", min_values=1, max_values=1)
    async def select_callback(self, interaction:discord.Interaction,select:discord.ui.Select):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Commands',
            colour=discord.Color.blue()
        )

        self.disabled = True
        value = select.values[0] # command's catagory
        
        commands_list = [command.name for command in self.bot.get_cog(value).get_commands()]  # Get command names in the category

        for command in commands_list:
            cmd = self.bot.get_command(command)
            docstring = cmd.callback.__doc__ or "No docstring"
            embed.add_field(name=command, value=docstring, inline=True)
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
            
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,view=OptionView())

